# thumbnails keep reloading on page scroll

Tags: html, css

The thumbnails on my photos page take a long time to load, then if you scroll down the page and back up, they have somehow vanished and need to reload. I'm using an old version of chrome on Windows XP, so I'm sure that's half my problem, BUT, it still does this on my cell (galaxy S5). I'm a novice coder so please go easy on me lol. Here is the link to my website and the photos page:

http://www.mikemicalizzicontracting.com/photos.html

Comment: You're going to have to provide a bit more information...like what tools you're using, and whatever you've tried to do. There's not much to go on here, I'm afraid.

Comment: You should resize your images first. You only use it in a very short format (like a thumbnail) and still have to download big images because you didn't resize. If there was only one, you wouldn't notice it, but here you have around 40, so that's a must

Comment: @Alburkerk  Thank you very much! I'll let you know how I make out!

Comment: @Alburkerk All set! All images were resized smaller and now behave normally! Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome, if my answer suited you, please accept the answer so the topic won't be opened / seen by other people who which to answer question and loose their time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really help you about your precise questions, as we don't have your code, but I am in a good mood so I'll just give you some tips to make your website quicker.

**Some tips for optimize your images :**

**1) Resize your images**

For now your images are displayed in 207 * 154, which is small, but you download them in their original size. You should resize them so the size of the image (in bits) would be much lower.

You can do that with a lot of online tools, or write a simple script for that in bash for instance. I think you will find a pre-made solution for the script very easily, or just have to download imagick (I am not sure of the name). This solution by scrip also depends on your distribution (wether you are usinc OSX, Windows, Linux..)

**2) Cache your images first**

It is always painful for the user to wait for images to display. So what you need to do is use browser cache (if you are novice you wil have some trouble but it will be worth it) to store the images data and then display them from this cache.

So the strategy is :

- If there is the image in cache, just display it from there
- If there isn't, download it from your server
- once it is loaded, put it in cache; then display it from there.

**3) (More advanced) Preload the images**

If your home page is very easy to display (not a lot if images, not that much script to run etc), you can start download some images in the client and just store them in the cache.

This task should always be a second-hand task, it means it should not slow your user navigation. So depending on what the user is doing, you may will have to pause the request and start it again.

If the user go on the photo page when an image is currently downloading for cache, you don't need to start it all over again, just continue.

This last tip can be long to develop, but this is a good thing to do when you want to display very good quality images or just plenty of them.